# Problems loading siunitx package

Tags: siunitx

I am facing weird problems trying to load the siunitx package. Version 2.7l is installed, all compulsory packages as well. I produced a minimal example where the same error occurs:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, headsepline, ngerman, openany, headings=small]{scrbook}

\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        detect-mode,
        tight-spacing       = true,
        group-digits        = false ,
        input-signs     = ,
        input-symbols       = ( ) [ ] - + *,
        input-open-uncertainty  = ,
        input-close-uncertainty = ,
        table-align-text-post   = false
        } 


\begin{document}

\si{1,2,3}

\end{document}
```

The error message tells me there is something wrong with the style file of the package:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \seq_const_from_clist:Nn
\c__siunitx_old_options_seq {addsign,all...
l.258 }
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
    <argument> ...list:Nn \c__siunitx_old_options_seq
    {addsign,allowlitunits,all...
    l.258 }

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
    See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
    Type H <return> for immediate help.
    ...
    l.258 }
```

Maybe someone has an idea how I can handle it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can run your code without problems (updated last week, MiKTeX, Win10). Maybe try to update your system again. As a last resort, deinstall and reinstall.

Comment: Almost certainly you have an old version of `l3kernel`: are you using MiKTeX?

Comment: The code works for me without problem on a fully updated MikTeX distribution on Windows 10. Your `siunitx` is up to date, so probably one of the `l3` packages is outdated. Have you tried an update?

Comment: Thank you! I reinstalled MiKTeX and after some adaption the code runs finally. Thank you all very very much

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, you might consider `newpxmath` as a replacement for `mathpazo`. Or even `unicode-math` with `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}` and `\setmathfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Asana Math}`.

Comment: see my answer here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450971/undefined-control-sequence-in-the-siunitx-sty-file/473469#473469

Comment: As of 2022 the `group-digits` setting of `siunitx` only takes the values `all`, `none`, `decimal`, and `integer`, so the line "`group-digits        = false ,`" may create an error.

Answer (score 4):

With the intention of adding more details, I verified that this is a version compatibility problem with **Miktex** and the `siunitx` package that is imported in the latest version. In my case the problem was with Miktex-2.9.6361 and **it was fixed by installing Miktex-2.9.6643**, which has important changes like how to manage packages and updates that is now done through a single interface called Miktex console.

[image]