# Undefined control sequence in the Siunitx sty file

Tags: miktex, installing, siunitx

I get this error each time i use siunitx. I am using siunitx version 2.7s, with miktex and texworks on PC.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
%%
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\end{document}
```

EDIT

Its been pointed out that the key issue may be that I am using an old version of MikTeX (without the console), so the question in part becomes, how do you update MikTex on Windows 8? and are there any problems with doing this?

here is a screenshot of me trying to update MikTex

[image]

Comment: Please tell us more about the TeX distribution and the version of the `siunitx` package that are installed on your computer. For what it's worth, I am unable to replicate the issue you describe on my system (MacTeX2018, all updates installed; version of `siunitx`: `2.7s`, date: 2018-05-17).

Comment: I am using miktex on a pc, how do i check whether my updates are installed?  I am using siunitx version 2.7s ?

Comment: When did you last update your MikTeX distribution?

Comment: I think Siunitx is up to date - i downloaded it for the first time this morning. When I tried to update miktex in response to your comment it failed. I am not sure why - here is a screenshot https://snag.gy/qwncMJ.jpg

Comment: This error is completely understandable. Judging from the screenshot you still have MikTeX without the console (the MikTeX update manager), which means your MikTeX is definitely not up-to-date, but you threw in an up-to-date package. Therefore I'm retagging this as MikTeX.

Comment: That sounds great. Is the solution as simple as uninstalling the old MikTex, and downloading and reinstalling the new MikTex?

Comment: If you're still using Windows 8, you're probably experiencing lots of computer-related problems...

Comment: hahah; not too many - I have to keep it on this OS for a little while so I can maintain backwards compatibility with some obscure academic software. I would rather a solution that isn't solve this minor problem by changing your OS. Perhaps I can find an older version of siunitx sty file

Comment: If you reinstall MikTeX you will lose all your current packages.  First try running the update (admin) program.  It should load the console.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the newest Miktex version and the newest update of siunitx.

After wasting too much precious time on this issue, I found a workaround by out-commenting lines 111-258 in siunitx.sty which seems related to some syntax compatibility with older versions:

```
% \exp_args:NNx \seq_const_from_clist:Nn \c__siunitx_old_options_seq
% {
% ...
% }
```

The workaround works for me, but I don't know which functionality might be affected.

Cheers

Comment: It's a really bad idea to change the code of a package. This specific piece of code is just to cope with deprecated options of the `siunitx` package. I'd suggest, if you should insist on changing the package code instead of updating, replacing `\seq_const_from_clist:Nn` by `\seq_gset_from_clist:Nn`, which would have (sort of) the same effect. But again: do not change the code of a package. Update!

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem for me.

Comment: thanks, for me too (on Debian 9 under TexLive).